# will ubuntu work on my ancient,pre-Pentium PowerMac G4 tower?

Tags: mac

Sorry if I'm repeating someone else's question but I'm a techno-illiterate,.... no formal computer training of any kind.  I need simple answers that aren't loaded with "terminology", please.

I use Firefox and Thunderbird and the email pkg. provided by a local company called Novus Communications. They also handle my landline and tv cable. They use fibre optic cabling if that's of any use. If you're from Vancouver, Canada you probably know of them.

My Mac was given to me and I did not know enough then to get the first owner's username and password so there's lots of downloadable stuff which I've never been able to dpownload. Argh!    But it gets worse,.... and it explains why I assume that very soon I'll no longer be able to use this old girl's 10.4.11 **OS**.  The internet now tells me it will no longer support either the T.Bird or the Firefox.

A friend tells me that since I cannot afford a new or even a 2nd hand new Mac that ubuntu may yet buy me some more years of use from this old, pre-Pentium PowerMac G4.
Help!
Paul from Vancouver, CA

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Ubuntu PowerPC FAQ](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ). If you understand it, great. If you don't...

Installing Ubuntu on a Power Mac G4 is a very technical process. Ask a computer geek to help you.
(Ironically, I'm writing this on a Power Mac G4 with Ubuntu.)

**EDIT:** Try out [TenFourFox](http://tenfourfox.com) and [TenFourBird](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/tenfourbird)!